# What's with the Winking eye animation?

Tags: clash-of-clans

As I scanned my Clans list of members (My Clan tab) I noticed that just one member (not me) had a different icon to the left of their name...

[image]

What was even more surprising was that it was animated - it winked!  I saw it winked at least twice.  Later it reverted to a more normal icon.  What did it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that there is a battle in progress on the castle of said clan member/the person is attacking someone and you can watch this by tapping the eye.